# Angular2 UrlSearchParams how to create url query with multiple values for same param with brackets

Tags: angular

How to properly use UrlSearchParams to create url a structure like the following:

```
example.org?tag[]=one&tag[]=two&tag[]=other
```

When I use Url Params as presented below:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('tag', 'one');
params.append('tag', 'two');
params.append('tag', 'other');
```

The Url looks like this:

```
example.org?tag=one&tag=two&tag=other
```

This approach causes some problems on web servers because they treat that query string the same way as `?tag=one`. The server gets only the first value if there are no brackets present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('tag[]', 'one');
params.append('tag[]', 'two');
params.append('tag[]', 'other');
```

Comment: This does no longer work, since the `[]` are encoded now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do something like this, but I haven't tested it:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('tag[0]', 'one');
params.append('tag[1]', 'two');
params.append('tag[2]', 'other');
```

Comment: Hi how can we pass key in tag dynamically. I mean as a variable.
eg: 'tag[key]'. I want to use it a for loop.